# Jenkins Pipeline does not find parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using the scripted syntax to define our multi-branch Jenkins pipeline (not declarative syntax). I want to add parameters that can be set when running the pipeline manually. This is supposed to work:

```
parameters([
    string(name: "Greeting", defaultValue: "Hello", description: "How should I greet the world?")
])

node('my-build') {
    checkout scm

    echo "${params.Greeting} World!"
```

Unfortunately all I get when running this is

> 08:40:56  [Pipeline] echo
> 08:40:56  null World!

I have tried numerous variations of this and none works. It seems as if the `Greeting` parameter isn't even set, I can add a `echo "${params.UNKNOWN_PARAM}"` and still get the null output in the console, so I don't think it's a missing value but a missing parameter (key).

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parameters` is not a Pipeline Step but a Declarative Pipeline directive. Since your pipeline definition uses Scripted syntax, not Declarative, the parameter is never added.

[Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) has examples of parameters defined using the declarative syntax.

In Scripted syntax, the `properties` step enables defining the parameters. [Pipeline Snippet Generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) can help you generate a step that will work on your controller. For example:

```
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How should I greet the world?', name: 'Greeting')])])
```

Note that parameters only show up after Pipeline is executed at least once. So on the first run parameter is likely to be empty, but on the second run you should see it there.

Comment: If you add a snippet that shows parameter declaration defined in a `properties` step, I will accept your answer.